# What type of variable is this and what type of statistical test?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

My dependent variable is a percent range (intervals of 4):

None
1-5%
6-10%
11-15%
16-20%
21-25%
26-30%
31-35%.....and so on until 100%

Is this an ordinal variable or an interval variable? What would be the best regression analysis to run for this type of variable?

Thank you

Comment: Ordinal, I think.

Comment: can i ask why you think it's ordinal and not interval?

Comment: I would call it interval. Regarding your second question, you can't pick a statistical test without defining what you want to infer about the data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'd like to know the relationship between several categorical variables and the dependent variable. My apologies, I should have stated "what type of regression analysis" would be best for this type of variable. The previous poster thought ordinal. Can I ask why you think it is interval?

Comment: @user3424836 Each interval is a level, thus ordered factors. You could look into something like ordered logit regression / ordinal regression.